# Как использовать addEventListener для всех элементов блока?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, listener, onclicklistener

Как в конце `addEventListener` сделать так, чтобы на ссылка, которую нажимаю, получала класс `active`. Я могу сделать это без `addEventListener` с помощю  `onclick="this"`, но нужно именно с `addEventListener`.

```js
var app1;

app1 = document.getElementById('appl');

appl.addEventListener('click', function(hdn) {
  var i, asa1;
  asa1 = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < asa1.length; i++) {
    asa1[i].classList.remove('active')
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <p>lorem600</p>
</div>
<div class="bottomNav" id="appl">
  <a href="#" class="active divA">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="divA">Bar</a>
  <a href="#" class="divA">Contacts</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В функцию-листенер передается аргументом экземпляр класса `Event`, и мы можем из его свойства `target` получить целевой элемент.

А добавление класса элементу быстрее всего выполняется через `<элемент>.classList.add(<имяКласса>);`.
<sub>Более медленные и некрасивые альтернативы - через свойство `className`, либо метод элемента `setAttribute()`.</sub>

```js
var appl = document.getElementById('appl');

appl.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('div-a'))         // если клик не по ссылке, просто завершим выполнение 
    return; 
  e.preventDefault();                                // отменим стандартную реакцию ссылки на клик
  for (let link of this.querySelectorAll('.div-a'))  // удалим класс active у всех наших ссылок... 
    link.classList.remove('active'); 
  e.target.classList.add('active');                  // ...и добавим его той, по которой выполнен клик
});
```

```css
.div-a { padding: 0.3em 0.5em; border: 1px solid transparent; }
.div-a.active { border-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="bottomNav" id="appl">
  <a href="#" class="div-a active">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="div-a">Bar</a>
  <a href="#" class="div-a">Contacts</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Также стоит обратить внимание на то, что `IE10` не поддерживает функции `forEach` и `addEventListener`. Поэтому моё решение без их использования. В IE можно использовать `attachEvent` вместо `addEventListener`.

**Вот так правильно:**

```js
var app1 = document.getElementById('appl');

appl.onclick = function(e)
{
    var i = 0,
        aElems = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        nodeName = e.target.nodeName.toUpperCase();

    //если нажатие не по ссылке, то выходим:
    if(nodeName != 'A')
        return !1; //false 

    //удаляем класс active у всех ссылок:
    for(; i < aElems.length; i++)
        aElems[i].classList.remove('active');

    //добавляем класс active только нажатой ссылке:
    if(nodeName == 'A')
        e.target.classList.add('active');
};
```

```css
.active
{
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    background-color: #9cf
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p><b>Нажмите на любую ссылку:</b></p>
</div>
<div class="bottomNav" id="appl">
  <a href="#" class="active divA">Home</a>
  <a href="#" class="divA">Bar</a>
  <a href="#" class="divA">Contacts</a>
</div>
```

Comment: А минусы за что?

Comment: @Arthur, есть тут всякие, которые то из чувства зависти, то из-за ещё чего просто ходят и минусуют. Придраться могут за всё. Вот сегодня, к примеру, [один докопался до меня](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/839957/#comment1346722_839974) тоже и потом минусанул мне.