# Как написать функцию для определения принадлежности точки к шестиугольнику?

Tags: javascript, canvas, гексагоны

Хочу узнать есть ли библиотеки или примеры кода на JS про то, как сделать проверку (true или false) принадлежности точки (x1, y1) к правильному шестиугольнику, у которого известны центр (x2, y2), а так же длинна ребра(z)?

Абсолютно строгим вычисление может и не быть и может проверять принадлежность к кругу внутри гексагона.

Желательно функция должна иметь вид:

```
var belongs = IsBelongingPointToHexagon(x1, y1, x2, y2, z);
```

Может в какой математической библиотеке завалялось или кто знает как это можно написать?

Задача у меня простая, в канвасе отрисовывается шестиугольный png и нужна проверка навели мышь на него или нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78981/discussion-on-question-by-aleksandr-sergeevich-----).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Примечание: готовый код приведён в конце ответа.*

*Шести*угольник можно разбить на шесть равносторонних *тре*угольников. Их вершины будут лежать в центре шестиугольника, *(x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>)*, а основания — на его сторонах:

[image: Изображение правильного шестиугольника]

Таким образом, проверка попадания точки в шестиугольник сводится к проверке попадания точки в какой-нибудь из этих треугольников.

Однако нет никакой необходимости перебирать все шесть треугольников. Во-первых, он правильный, а во-вторых — симметричный. Поэтому достаточно зеркально отразить проверяемую точку в первый квадрант (*x*≥0; *y*≥0) и проверить только *два* треугольника:

[image: Изображение правильного шестиугольника]

Теперь о том, как проверить наличие точки в треугольнике:

1. Находим положение проверяемой точки относительно центра шестиугольника. Точнее, нам нужно не само положение, а модуль его координат (помним про первую четверть):

   ```
   var x = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
   var y = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
   ```
2. Проходимся по периметру треугольника и проверяем, что на всех трёх сторонах точка находится от нас по одну и ту же руку (правую или левую):

   ```
   // Вычисляем знаковые углы (почти) между точкой и гранями
   var ab_p_angle = (xa - x) * (yb - y) - (xb - x) * (ya - y);
   var bc_p_angle = (xb - x) * (yc - y) - (xc - x) * (yb - y);
   var ac_p_angle = (xc - x) * (ya - y) - (xa - x) * (yc - y);

   // Точка лежит внутри треугольника, если все эти углы имеют одинаковый знак
   var is_inside = (ab_p_angle * ab_p_angle > 0) && (bc_p_angle * ac_p_angle > 0);
   ```

Наконец о том, как быстро получить координаты вершин треугольников. С первой вершиной всё просто — это центр шестиугольника. А вот с остальными всё несколько сложнее:

[image: Изображение правильного шестиугольника]

Верхняя точка — это высота равностороннего треугольника. Такие сложные координаты взяты потому, что при выборе точек прямо на осях симметрии мы получаем нули, позволяющие выкинуть часть множителей из последующих уравнений.

Получив точки, возвращаемся к формулам площади треугольников 0-1-2 и 0-3-2:

[image: Изображение правильного шестиугольника]

Такой порядок обхода выбран для сохранения ориентации стороны 0-2. Это позволит использовать одно и то же значение расстояния для обоих треугольников.

А теперь уравнения:

```
var px0 = 0,                            py0 = 0;
var px1 = 0,                            py1 = z * Math.sqrt(3) / 2;
var px2 = z * sin(3.14 / 4 - 3.14 / 6), py2 = z * cos(3.14 / 4 - 3.14 / 6);
var px3 = z,                            py3 = 0;

// Отслеживаем направления по картинке выше
//                x1         y2         x2         y1
var p_angle_01 = (px0 - x) * (py1 - y) - (px1 - x) * (py0 - y);
var p_angle_20 = (px2 - x) * (py0 - y) - (px0 - x) * (py2 - y);
var p_angle_03 = (px0 - x) * (py3 - y) - (px3 - x) * (py0 - y);
var p_angle_12 = (px1 - x) * (py2 - y) - (px2 - x) * (py1 - y);
var p_angle_32 = (px3 - x) * (py2 - y) - (px2 - x) * (py3 - y);
```

Теперь подставляем:

```
var px0 = x2,               py0 = y2;
var px1 = 0,                py1 = z * 0.86602540378;
var px2 = z * 0.2588190451, py2 = z * 0.96592582628;
var px3 = z,                py3 = 0;

var p_angle_01 = (0 - x) * (py1 - y) - (0 - x) * (0 - y);
var p_angle_20 = (px2 - x) * (0 - y) - (0 - x) * (py2 - y);
var p_angle_03 = (0 - x) * (0 - y) - (z - x) * (0 - y);
var p_angle_12 = (0 - x) * (py2 - y) - (px2 - x) * (py1 - y);
var p_angle_32 = (z - x) * (py2 - y) - (px2 - x) * (0 - y);
```

... и сокращаем:

```
var p_angle_01 = -x * (py1 - y) - x * y;
var p_angle_20 = -y * (px2 - x) + x * (py2 - y);
var p_angle_03 = y * z;
var p_angle_12 = -x * (py2 - y) - (px2 - x) * (py1 - y);
var p_angle_32 = (z - x) * (py2 - y) + y * (px2 - x);
```

Наконец, собираем всё вместе в готовую функцию:

```
function IsBelongingPointToHexagon(x1, y1, x2, y2, z)
{
    var x = Math.abs(x1 - x2), y = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

    var py1 = z * 0.86602540378;
    var px2 = z * 0.2588190451;
    var py2 = z * 0.96592582628;

    var p_angle_01 = -x * (py1 - y) - x * y;
    var p_angle_20 = -y * (px2 - x) + x * (py2 - y);
    var p_angle_03 = y * z;
    var p_angle_12 = -x * (py2 - y) - (px2 - x) * (py1 - y);
    var p_angle_32 = (z - x) * (py2 - y) + y * (px2 - x);

    var is_inside_1 = (p_angle_01 * p_angle_12 >= 0) && (p_angle_12 * p_angle_20 >= 0);
    var is_inside_2 = (p_angle_03 * p_angle_32 >= 0) && (p_angle_32 * p_angle_20 >= 0);

    return is_inside_1 || is_inside_2;
}
```

Comment: Сделано предположение, что две стороны шестиугольника параллельны оси X. Откуда?

Comment: @AnT, это один из вариантов. Если он неверный, то можно либо пересчитать коэффициенты при `pxN`/`pyN`, либо добавить в формулу перевода точки в первый квадрант умножение на матрицу поворота (то есть заменить `x1 - x2` и `y1 - y2` на `A * xr + B * yr` и `C * xr + D * yr` при `xr = x1 - x2; yr = y1 - y2`.

Comment: Ух какая работа! завтра проверю, спасибо :)

Comment: ошибка, нет переменной  p_angle_32, заменил ее `на p_angle_23`, в итоге высчитывает не правильно попадания, более-менее правильно считает только правый верхний угол

Comment: @Arhad, почему вы даже не проверили свой код на работоспособность? Это самое первое, ЧТО ОБЯЗАН СДЕЛАТЬ РАЗРАБОТЧИК! ;-)

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich, исправил. Там мало было заменить имя переменной — сам порядок обхода был неправильный. Если проследить по иллюстрации с порядком обхода, видно, что надо было идти именно в порядке 3-2, а не 2-3. К тому же исправил неравенства в `is_inside` на строгие, чтобы стыки треугольников тоже считались внутренней частью шестиугольника.

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich, обнаружил ещё ошибку ложноположительного срабатывания. Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich, исправил. Я центр шестиугольника помещал не в нуле (ибо локальная система координат, ради перехода к которой и изменялись координаты проверяемой точки), а в *(x2; y2)*.

Comment: @Bharata, согласен, поспешил. Сейчас [вроде всё работает](https://pastebin.com/bqWqihbq).

Comment: @Arhad, вам нужно ещё проверить именно на канвасе! ;-)

Comment: @Arhad И у меня работает на канвасе. Только почему-то при уменьшении масштаба картинки (т.е. отрисовываемая ширина умножается на масштаб, соответственно когда необходимо картинку уменьшить ширина и высота умножается например на 0.5), то в этом случае отклик смещается выше картинки. При уменьшении в 10 раз отклик уже совсем не соответствует положению картинки, аналогично и при увеличении. Как думаете, существует погрешность при расчетах?

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich что из координат  и как вы пересчитываете перед передачей в `IsBelongingPointToHexagon` при масштабировании? Координаты курсора (*x1*, *y1*) умножаете на масштаб, или делаете это только для *x2*, *y2* и *z*?

Comment: @Arhad я так понял, что у вашего кода нет погрешности и ищу ошибку у себя

Comment: Прикрутил вариант @Bharata , дописал ему соответствующие функции и проверил. В общем это я не правильно передаю параметры при изменении масштаба картинки т.к. с его ф-ией координаты определяются так же как и с Вашей. Сейчас затестю, что быстрее работает

Answer (score 4):

**Использование встроенной функции [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath)  – вот верное решение**

Вам только нужно изменить ваш неверно выбранный изначально подход – нужно добавлять шестиугольники через добавление координат их вершин.

**Пример с применением встроенной функции:**

> **[`CanvasRenderingContext2D.isPointInPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath)** (ссылка на документацию)
>
> Эта функция может принимать также в качестве первого аргумента объект **[`Path2D`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D)**, но это не поддерживается IE и Safari (поэтому в этом примере объект `Path2D` не используется).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 25);
ctx.lineTo(100, 25);
ctx.lineTo(125, 68);
ctx.lineTo(100, 111);
ctx.lineTo(50, 111);
ctx.lineTo(25, 68);
ctx.closePath();

canvas.onmousemove = function(e)
{
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 ctx.fillStyle = ctx.isPointInPath(e.pageX, e.pageY) ? 'blue' : 'green';
 ctx.fill();
};

//это для отрисовки первого раза (иначе не рисуется пока мышкой не навести):
canvas.onmousemove({});
```

```css
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}

p
{
    color: green;
    font: bold 16px "Courier New";
    margin-left: 14px
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="130" height="130"></canvas>
<p>Наведите мышкой на шестиугольник</p>
```

> Обратите внимание на то что для простоты примера используются координаты мышки без учёта прокрутки (смещения) страницы и их нужно ещё доработать. Хотя для этого примера этого достаточно.

---

**Невстроенную функцию** (*если таковая вообще нужна*), определяющую принадлежность точки к шестиугольнику `pointInHexagon`, вы найдёте на **[enSO по ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40776715/)**.

Нижеследующая функция проверяет принадлежность точки к кругу:

```
// x, y – координаты точки
// cx, cy середина круга
// r - radius круга

function pointInCircle(x, y, cx, cy, r)
{
    return (x - cx) * (x - cx) + (y - cy) * (y - cy) <= r * r;
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78982/discussion-on-answer-by-bharata------).